# View like Task manager with filter

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I'm trying to make an app where I could see the process, path, user, and description like Task Manager Details, which I have made but I want a filter to search from the source code where the image path contains 'Chrome' for example or If you could help me to get the Description like the task manager image and filter with this column. If you can help me to get the username of the process without using the another method will  be nice.

Thank you.

This is what i have improved.

```
DataTable dt = null;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wmiQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process";
        //  var wmiQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem";
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
        using (var results = searcher.Get())
        {
            var query = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                        join mo in results.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                        on p.Id equals (int)(uint)mo["ProcessId"]
                        select new
                        {
                            Process = p.ProcessName,
                            Path = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"],
                            CommandLine = (string)mo["CommandLine"],
                            User = GetProcessOwner(p.Id),
                            Description = mo["Description"]
                        };
            dt = ConvertToDataTable(query);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

    }
    DataTable ConvertToDataTable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        var props = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(
          props.Select(p => new DataColumn(p.Name, p.PropertyType)).ToArray()
        );

        source.ToList().ForEach(
          i => dt.Rows.Add(props.Select(p => p.GetValue(i, null)).ToArray())
        );
        Array a = source.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {

            var x = a.GetValue(i);
            //if (true)
            //{
            //    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
            //    r.
            //}



            a.ToString();
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public string GetProcessOwner(int processId)
    {
        string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId; ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query); ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get(); foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
        {
            string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty }; int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList)); if (returnVal == 0)
            {
               // return DOMAIN\user 
               return argList[0]; 
            }
        }
        return "NO OWNER";
    }
```

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo0Uy.png)

[TaskManager what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MbJl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process description comes from the file description.  You can grab it like so:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var wmiQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process";
  //  var wmiQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem";
  using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
  using (var results = searcher.Get())
  {
    var query = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                join mo in results.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                on p.Id equals (int)(uint)mo["ProcessId"]
                select new
                {
                  Process = p.ProcessName,
                  Path = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"],
                  CommandLine = (string)mo["CommandLine"],
                  User = GetProcessOwner(p.Id),
                  Description = GetDescription((string)mo["ExecutablePath"])
                };
    dt = ConvertToDataTable(query);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
  }
}

string GetDescription(string executablePath)
{
  if (!File.Exists(executablePath))
  {
    return "No Description";
  }

  return FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(executablePath).FileDescription;
}
```

You'll probably need to run your program as an administrator to show the details of all processes.

Why would you like to get the username with another method?

Comment: Not another method, I dont want to, I was specting something like: mo["UserName"]